# Bash Remove Variable Field

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script that splits a .txt file into two separate files based on the value of one of a field within. I need to remove the values  conntained in the company_id column before writing to the file, like below:

Input: input.txt

```
id|fname |lname    |company_id
1 |Bob   |Jones    |1234
2 |Mary  |Stewart  |5678    
3 |Miguel|Velazquez|5678
4 |Sara  |Brooks   |1234
```

Output 1: Company_A.txt

```
id|fname |lname    
1 |Bob   |Jones    
4 |Sara  |Brooks
```

Output 2: Company_B.txt

```
id|fname |lname      
2 |Mary  |Stewart      
3 |Miguel|Velazquez
```

The problem comes when I want to use this bash script for the same purpose on another file where the company_id column, instead of being column 4 might be column 15. I have figured out a way to store the column number in variable COMANY_ID_COL, but then want to use that value to remove the field in the output. Here's what I have so far:

```
   while read p; do

    # If this is the first pass through the loop grab the column heading and save it
    if [ "$COUNTER" = "0" ]; then
        ((COUNTER++))
        COL_HEADING=$p

        COMPANY_ID_COL_NUM="$(echo $p | awk -F\| '{for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {if($i == "company_id") {print i}}}')"

        # remove the correct column from line by using value stored in $COMPANY_ID_COL_NUM
        ?????????

    else 
        # Grab the COMPANY_ID from the column in the input file
        # Note: not yet set up to use the variable COMPANY_ID_COL_NUM which will change to a variable instead of the last col
        COMPANY_ID="$(echo $p | awk -F\| '{print $(NF)}')"

            #If COMPANY_ID matches value, format filename for ouptut
                if [ $COMPANY_ID -eq 1234 ]
                then 
                    COMP="CompanyA"
                    FILENAME="${COMP}.txt"
                    echo $FILENAME;
                elif [ $COMPANY_ID -eq 5678 ]
                then 
                    COMP="CompanyB";
                    FILENAME="${COMP}.txt"
                    echo $FILENAME;
                else
                    COMP="Neither";
                    FILENAME="${COMP}.txt"
                    echo $FILENAME;
                fi

        # If there isn't a file already create it and add the column heading to it
        if [ ! -f $FILENAME ]; then
            echo $COL_HEADING >> $FILENAME          
        fi

        # Output current line into output files
        echo $p >> $FILENAME 

    fi

# File to use as input
done < input.txt
```

Comment: Can `company_id` be in the middle of row as well?

Comment: What does the script that does the column removal/splitting look like currently?

Comment: @anubhava : Yes - the company_id could be in the middle of a row as well, as in: id|fname|lname|address|company_id|mname|order_num|total|

Comment: @EtanReisner `#If company_id belongs, create filename to output</n>
    if [ $COMPANY_ID -eq 1234 ]
    then 
     COMP="CompanyA"
     FILENAME="{COMP}.txt"
     echo $FILENAME;
    elif[ $COMPANY_ID -eq 5678 ]
    then 
     COMP="CompanyB"
     FILENAME="4{COMP}.txt"
     echo $FILENAME;
    else
     COMP="Neither";
     FILENAME="${COMP}.txt";
     echo $FILENAME;
    fi

  # If not exists create file and add heading to it
  if [ ! -f $FILENAME ]; then
   echo $COL_HEADING >> $FILENAME   
  fi# Output current line into output file
  echo $p >> $FILENAME`

Comment: Edit that into your post please so the formatting remains sane.

Comment: @EtanReisner done. See original question above with full text of the script

Answer (score 0):

I guess this command line will do the trick:

```
for i in `cat input.txt | awk -F'|' {' print $4'} OFS="|" | grep -e [0-9]`; do head -n1 input.txt |  awk -F'|' {' print $1, $2, $3'} OFS="|" > company_$i.txt; grep $i input.txt |  awk -F'|' {' print $1, $2, $3'} OFS="|" >> company_$i.txt;  donee
```

Or if you want in a script file:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `cat $1 | awk -F'|' {' print $4'} OFS="|" | grep -e [0-9]`; do
head -n1 $1 | awk -F'|' {' print $1, $2, $3'} OFS="|" > output_$i.txt
grep $i $1 | awk -F'|' {' print $1, $2, $3'} OFS="|" >> output_$i.txt
done
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with awk, it's pretty straightforard:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '
    NR == 1 {header = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3; next}
    { 
        f = "Company_" $4 ".txt"; 
        if (!seen[f]) {
            print header > f
            seen[f] = 1
        }
        print $1,$2,$3 > f 
    }
' input.txt
```

Comment: OP indicates that number of columns and which column is `company_id` are not fixed details. This would need to find the right column and only elide that column.